# Doctrine : how to use Replace function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need your help to build my query with Doctrine. I am a symfony beginner.
Firstly I built my query inside MySQL SQL tab and it's working fine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM contact
WHERE insee like '03%'
ORDER BY (LENGTH(tif) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tif,";",""))) DESC

To be more precise, my tif field looks like that : 
1 - 01.02.01.02;01.02.03.04;01.05.06 (3 subsets)
2 - 01.02.03.08.07.01.02.03.08.0701.02.03.08.07; (1 subset)
3 - 01.02.01;02.06.05 (2 subsets)
```

I need to get the number of codes order by desc so as to get the order 1,3,2.

Now I tried to build it in my repository class on Symfony
I found out that replace function doesn't exist upon Doctrine so I tried to skirt it by doing what follows :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from('SgaContactBundle:Contact', 'c')
            ->where('c.insee LIKE :insee')
            ->setParameter('insee', '%' . $insee . '%');

$qb->orderBy($qb->expr()->diff(
            $qb->expr()->length('c.tif'), 
            $qb->expr()->length(preg_match_all('/;/i', 'c.tif')) ),
            'DESC');
return $qb->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
```

Finally I've got this error :

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 99: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | 
 InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '0'
```

What can I do in order to replace "Replace function" ?
I tried preg_replace, preg_match and finally preg_match_all but something goes wrong.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: I don't get why `ORDER BY X DESC` with `X` an integer is okay since `X` is supposed to be a field ? Can you give an example of what `c.tif` looks like and what do you expect from your `ORDER BY (...)` expression to do ?

Comment: I edited my post. I am sorry ...
As I wrote above my tif field looks like that : 
1 - 01.02.01.02;01.02.03.04;01.05.06 (3 subsets)
2 - 01.02.03.08.07.01.02.03.08.0701.02.03.08.07; (1 subset)
3 - 01.02.01;02.06.05 (2 subsets)

Comment: Okay I got it thanks! You might consider using an extra column having the number of subset for each `tif` field. You could sort your result more easily ! But I'm not sure at all this is a good practice... Let me check other options

Answer (score 8):

You can implement your own function like the validate response, OR you can use this Doctrine Extension package that include REPLACE() mysql function and much more (Match against, ROUND, ASIN...) : https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Simply install this to your project

```
composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
```

And add the function you want (only) into your config.yml doctrine conf :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
        #...
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    match: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\MatchAgainst
                    replace: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Replace
```

Here is a small exemple for REPLACE in query builder :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ts')
    ->where("REPLACE(ts.reference, ' ','') LIKE :reference")
    ->setParameter('reference', $reference)
;
```

Hope it can help someone after